# Where to easily store HTML content for a custom tag helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following custom tag helper

```
public class PageHeaderTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string HeaderContent { get; set; }

    private string Template { get; set; } = $@"<h2 class='pageheader-title'>{{0}}</h2>";

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "div";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "page-header");

        output.Content.AppendHtml(string.Format(Template, HeaderContent));

    }
}
```

The thing is sometimes, the `Template` can get pretty big and storing its content in a string variable isn't the most convenient (readability, double quotes needing to be converted to single quotes, etc.)

I've thought of using a resource file and pasting the HTML code in it, that's a bit better.

But is there a way to simply paste the HTML markup in a separate physical file to it's easily readable and editable and usable from the tag helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the HTML code in a html page in wwwroot folder like `wwwroot/mypage.html`:

```
<h2 class="pageheader-title">Hello World</h2>
```

In TageHelper, you could get it using:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var Template = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("wwwroot/mypage.html");
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(Template);
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/th-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#inject-into-html-body-element

Comment: Yes, seems like it's the way to go. I could also implement something with `MemoryCache` to prevent to much hard drive reads.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store your HTML in an invisible tag. Create a div and hide it. With this approach, your HTML templates can be easily queried by JavaScript. You can also separate your HTML templates in another file without the doctype nor body tags and embed it into your main document.

Comment: OP asks how-to server side, using a TagHelper, not client side, using javascript.